# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue when using Restangular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, laravel

I'm trying to use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) in my AngularJS application to access a REST API and I'm facing an issue with the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. I know that this needs to be returned with the API response for security reasons and it *is* being returned, but for some reason `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't seem to be noticing it.

The full error message is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mysite.dev/users. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mysite.dev' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

If I look at the request in the Network tab of Chrome's dev tools, I can see that the header **is** being set on the response:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code that I'm using to serve those headers in my Laravel REST application:

```
Route::options('{all}', function ()
{
    $response = Response::make('');

    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type');

    return $response;
})
->where('all', '.*');
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you are showing the OPTIONS request and response, but not the POST request and response. What do those show?

Comment: That was it Quentin, thanks. The OPTIONS request had the right headers but the POST request that followed it didn't. Didn't realize Chrome's dev tools refused to show the request if it was disallowed by access control.

Answer (score -1):

Try these additional Access-Control-Allow-Headers:

```
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,content-type,accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since');
```

Comment: This is for nginx but the principle is the same - http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html